# Can we create file under a symlinked directory?

Tags: symlink

Say I have a directory called /data, which contains 3 files: a.txt, b.txt and c.txt

I am linking it to another directory using:

> > > ln -s /data /this/is/temp

Then, if I want to create another file d.txt in /data, can I use the symlink directory instead?

> > > touch /this/is/temp/d.txt

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.  Symlinks to directories can be used in paths just as if they were real directories.